# Spark - Remove Header and Trailer from CSV files

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to ingest CSV files in table, However before that I need to do some validation based on Header and Trailer.

**Sample Data**

```
Header,TestApp,2020-01-01,
name, dept, age, batchDate
john, dept1, 33, 2020-01-01
john, dept1, 33, 2020-01-01
john, dept1, 33, 2020-01-01
john, dept1, 33, 2020-01-01
Trailer,count,4
```

Now before I ingest data into table, I need to check that total count of records are 5 as per trailer record.

This is what I am doing right.

```scala
val df = spark.read.format("csv").load("/tmp/test.csv")
val indexed = df.withColumn("index", monotonicallyIncreasingId())
val last = indexed.agg(max($"index")).collect()(0)(0).asInstanceOf[Long]
//Remove header and Trailer record
val filtered  = indexed.filter($"index" < last).filter($"index" >= 1)

//Write file without extra header and trailer, it still have column name
filtered.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save("/tmp/test1")

//Read back with infer schema
val df1 = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load("/tmp/test1")

//Count Validation
val count = indexed.filter($"index" === last).select("_c1").collect()(0)(0).asInstanceOf[String].toInt
assert(df.count == count)
```

I was thinking, if there is a better way to avoid writing back the files to create second dataframe. I am talking about 5th Step.

I would like to have final dataframe with `inferschme` and `column header` from the column header (second row from file)?

Answer (score 3):

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Column, Encoders, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, trim}

val df1 = spark.read.option("header", false).csv(f)

val colNames = List("name", "dept", "age", "batchDate")
val df2 = df1
  .filter('_c0 =!= "Header")
  .filter('_c0 =!= "Trailer")
  .filter('_c0 =!= "name")
df2.show(false)

//  +----+------+---+-----------+
//  |_c0 |_c1   |_c2|_c3        |
//  +----+------+---+-----------+
//  |john| dept1| 33| 2020-01-01|
//  |john| dept1| 33| 2020-01-01|
//  |john| dept1| 33| 2020-01-01|
//  |john| dept1| 33| 2020-01-01|
//  +----+------+---+-----------+

val df3 = df2.toDF(colNames: _*)

df3.show(false)
//    +----+------+---+-----------+
//    |name|dept  |age|batchDate  |
//    +----+------+---+-----------+
//    |john| dept1| 33| 2020-01-01|
//    |john| dept1| 33| 2020-01-01|
//    |john| dept1| 33| 2020-01-01|
//    |john| dept1| 33| 2020-01-01|
//    +----+------+---+-----------+

df3.printSchema()
//  root
//  |-- name: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- dept: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- age: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- batchDate: string (nullable = true)

case class SchemaClass(name: String, dept: String, age: Int, batchDate: String)
val schema: StructType    = Encoders.product[SchemaClass].schema
val sch = df3.schema
val schemaDiff = schema.diff(sch)

val rr = schemaDiff.foldLeft(df3)((acc, clmn) => {
  acc.withColumn(clmn.name , trim(col(clmn.name)).cast(clmn.dataType))
})

rr.show(false)
//  +----+------+---+-----------+
//  |name|dept  |age|batchDate  |
//  +----+------+---+-----------+
//  |john| dept1|33 | 2020-01-01|
//  |john| dept1|33 | 2020-01-01|
//  |john| dept1|33 | 2020-01-01|
//  |john| dept1|33 | 2020-01-01|
//  +----+------+---+-----------+


rr.printSchema
//  root
//  |-- name: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- dept: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- age: integer (nullable = true)
//  |-- batchDate: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: is there a way I can infer schema as well. I suppose all the columns in `df3` will be string.

Comment: You can try use df3.schema , and your schema (what you need). + foldLeft. After done my work day I give example, if you need.

Comment: oh, I don't have any schma available, I just have to get schema from using inferschema.

Comment: Added changed type fields with schema. 
>> I just have to get schema from using inferschema. then you need remove first and last line file for receive corect schema

Comment: the problem. I don't know in advance the schema of file. So I can't create case class

Comment: undestand. sorry.